# Dell Laptop won't turn on until I perform an electrical discharge on it

Tags: dell-inspiron

I've been facing a problem from the past week that whenever I hibernate my laptop, it won't start on the next time. I fixed this by performing an electrical discharge by unplugging the adapter and battery and holding down the power button. I shut down the laptop from there on and it worked fine. Now after my last boot even after shutting down I need to perform an electrical discharge everytime. How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you disable hibernating? Does it shutdown & boot normally then?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: In UEFI/BIOS, disable Fast Boot and test.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem started at a known time, you can review other things that happened approximately that time.  Assuming you're using Windows 10, it's possible that the Windows 10v1809 update or a driver update is not working properly.  Look in Settings->Update & Security-> View Update History.  Review for updates applied during and slightly before the problem started.  If any exist, click "Uninstall updates" and sort by date.  Right-click the suspect updates and click "Uninstall".

In general, it's not good to force-shutdown the PC repeatedly.  If you can't make hibernation work properly, disable hibernation in Control Panel->Power Options->open the active plan->Advanced Power Settings->Sleep.  Disable 'Allow hybrid sleep' and 'Hibernate after'.  This means that your laptop will use a little power while the lid is closed, so if you find it running down the battery, you can Shut Down when you're done with it.

Comment: According to OP's description, it seems like the laptop shuts down correctly, but doesn't boot up.

Comment: That tells me that it doesn't shut down all the way but hibernates, badly.  Windows 10 changed the generic shutdown/startup procedure to be more like Hibernate was in Win7.  I suspect if OP performs a rollback of recent software updates, they will get the desired behavior back.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation